# Shell command in r doesn't work with space in directory name

Tags: r, shell

I'm trying to run simple external application from R using shell command.

```
shell('"C:\\Program Files\\SomeApp\\bin\\Release\\SomeApp.exe" "C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\R_Scripts\\RProjects\\Rprojects\\" "1" "yes"')
```

If I run part in brackets from command line it works perfectly. But if I run it via R's shell command it throws me an error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\SomeApp\bin\Release\SomeApp.exe" "C:\Users\SomeUser\R_Scripts\RProjects\Rprojects\" "1" "yes"' had status 1 
2: In shell("\"C:\\Program Files\\SomeApp\\bin\\Release\\SomeApp.exe\" \"C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\R_Scripts\\RProjects\\Rprojects\\\" \"1\" \"yes\"") :
 '"C:\Program Files\SomeApp\bin\Release\SomeApp.exe" "C:\Users\SomeUser\R_Scripts\RProjects\Rprojects\" "1" "yes"' execution failed with error code 1
```

Does anybody else facing the same issue?

Comment: Try backslashing the spaces - "C:\\Program\ Files ...."

Comment: No, still the same error message.

Comment: I don't have windows here, so I cannot test, but in other R function on windows (such as read.table) you have to use slash (/) instead of backslash (\) (UNIX style).

Comment: I tried that but doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

Space separated text should be double quoted. This works for R's shell command.

```
shell('C:\\"Program Files"\\SomeApp\\bin\\Release\\SomeApp.exe "C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\R_Scripts\\RProjects\\Rprojects\\" "1" "yes"')
```

Comment: Your double quotes don't balance properly in that answer, so I'm surprised it worked.  But quoting in Windows shells is very poorly documented, so maybe `cmd.exe` doesn't care.  If you need other special characters in the command, see the help page for the R function `shQuote()`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made a fix in above answer. It should be fine now.