# How can R pass a filename with spaces to Windows 'cmd'?

Tags: r

How can the `shell` command in R 3.6.1 pass a file name with spaces to Windows 10.0.18362 `cmd`?

Consider these examples:

```
shell('"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF.exe" "C:/Program Files/file.pdf"') # fails (could not find "C:/Program")
shell('"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF.exe"  C:/Program Files/file.pdf ') # tries to open two nonexisting files
shell('"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF.exe" "C:/Windows/otherFile.pdf"')  # fails as well
shell('"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF.exe"  C:/Windows/otherFile.pdf ')  # works
```

All of them work if copypasted (without single quotes) in `cmd` directly (the second one not with the intended result).
I'd be happy to use an other function than `shell`. Note I originally receive the exe name and the file name as separate charstrings.

This is related to [Shell command in r doesn't work with space in directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923227/shell-command-in-r-doesnt-work-with-space-in-directory-name), but that answer does not seem to apply here.

Comment: `shell('notepad.exe "c:/users/hongo/documents/file with spaces.txt"')` works here. Check that your file actually exists (it should not be in 'Program Files' for starters)

Comment: Look for `shQuote`, it's typically better than manually adding quotes for shell purposes.

Comment: `system(paste(shQuote(c("/path to/exe", "/path/to/space dir/file.pdf")), collapse=" "))` works for me

Comment: r2evans: that works! I'm so happy! The first example with `system` instead of `shell` works as well. I thought I had tried all... Do you want to turn your comment to an answer?